# Is there any easy way (hack) to expose a header hidden by forward declaration?

Tags: c++, c, ssl, openssl, forward-declaration

I know this question sounds very silly... 
I am working at a project which uses lots of openssl library. I am current working on upgrading the used library from 1.0 to 1.1 and this gives me lots of hard time. Openssl community decides to make nobody access their internal structure of BIO, SSL, RSA, EVP_PKEY anymore. This seems a good direction but I have thousands of lines of code using these structure (such as `EVP_PKEY *key; key->reference = XXX;`).

I notice that openssl hide these code by forward declaration (i.e., separating a public header to a public header + a private header).

For example, the code in the old structure looks like:
include/obj.h:

```
   struct obj_st {
     int property1, int property2 ....etc
   }
```

The new structure becomes
include/obj.h:

```
   struct obj_st;
```

include/obj_private.h:

```
   struct obj_st {
     int property1, int property2 ....etc
   }
```

In this case, after I compile the whole openssl as a static library. My code including it by `#include<openssl/obj.h>` is no longer able to access these properties.

An easy way to handle it would be that I just move all these private header files back to the original format (w/o forward declaration). But it means that I need to do it every time when I pull the new openssl code.

Is there any easy hack that I can make all of them exposed again? I am thinking to include the private header in my code as well (such as `#include<openssl/obj_private.h>`), but many of private headers also have dependency on other headers, which turns out that I need to copy all the headers to my usr/include/openssl folder. I am not sure if it is a good idea to do....

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to be using the structure members? By only forward declaring the structure it's meant to be a "black box", something which you should not look at the internals of. Much like a `FILE` from standard C.

Comment: It would work to just copy the struct definitions you need into your own header file, which you would store in your project, and you must update it to match whatever version of OpenSSL you are using.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude He seems to understand that, but he has lots of legacy code that accesses the structure members because it used to be allowed.

Comment: @Barmar It's still a better idea to refactor the legacy code IMO. What if (and when) the structures change? What happens if members are renamed or even disappear completely? Better bite the bullet now and make sure the code is future-proof than panicking later and rushing bad and under-tested fixes later.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But In C, is not very surprising and the user can choice to freeze the version of the library. I don't like opaque structure in C. Tell to the user "if you access to these fields directly be aware that it's your problem" is better in C. `FILE` is an exception because it's os-depend.

Comment: Hi, thank you for all your comments. It gives me some great confidence that I need to (sadly) refactor my code to adapt this change.

Comment: *"I am current working on upgrading the used library from 1.0 to 1.1 and this gives me lots of hard time..."* - Checkout the OpenSSL compatibility library at [openssl-compat.tar.gz](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes#Backward_compatibility). It mostly allows you to use OpenSSL 1.0.2 code with OpenSSL 1.1.0. It was used to provide the [patches for OpenSSH (Pull Request #48)](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/pull/48) so SSH gear could build against OpenSSL 1.1.0.

Comment: Instead of reaching into OpenSSL objects directly, like `key->reference`, you should probably provide a compatibility layer with setters and getters (similar to the way OpenSSL did). You can break the encapsulation in a controlled way that does not grossly abuse the API and does not trash the memory arena.

Comment: Since they have been made opaque there are many OpenSSL internal structures which have changed significantly. For example if you compare the 1.1.0 version of ssl_st with the 1.0.2 version you will note some major changes. This trend is likely to continue.

Comment: @Stargateur *But In C, is not very surprising and the user can choice to freeze the version of the library.*  Freezing on a specific version of OpenSSL is a very, very bad idea.  What do you do **when** a major security problem is discovered in OpenSSL? If you freeze on a specific version, you can't do anything quickly and you're forced to either shutdown or knowingly run with a security issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Short version:* you don't.

*Long version:* there is a serious reason library developers are trying to make public API as narrow and simple as possible, while hiding implementation details from library users. The reason is, the code that's not a part of the API might be changed without any announcement and freely, as long as the API contracts are maintained.

The main point is, if library developers decided to hide something that was previously exposed (which is a very strong move itself which I'm not aware of, but I believe you), they have a serious intention to change this code significantly in the future. If they do this at some point, your code will break anyway in a most twisted way (considering you'll be willing to upgrade, which I guess you will based on your question) - and the access to structure members will not help you.

So, unfortunately, the best course of action for you is to refactor you code in order to use new, less convenient API. Being both library developer *and* library user, I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you might be right in general, but I really don't think doing this (hiding structures) is really reasonable for openssl. Especially when their website claims the new update is "API compatible...". Personally, I don't think they are going to change the structure because many of their own code also include lots of hack of manipulating the structure (like creating a new structure based on old structure but change the function pointer to other places). So, it is unclear why openssl community decides on doing this....

Comment: @Yu-Chih OpenSSL does *not* claim that 1.1.0 is API or ABI compatible with 1.0.2. It only claims that minor releases are, i.e. ones that change the last digit. So 1.0.2 is API/ABI compatible with 1.0.1. The forthcoming 1.1.1 is API/ABI compatible with 1.1.0. But 1.0.2 to 1.1.0 was a major release (changed the middle number), so this does not apply.

Comment: @Yu-Chih Reaching directly into the structures is bypassing the API.  The API can be perfectly stable, yet changes to the underlying code and structures will still break code that bypasses that API. Unfortunately, you're now dealing with the consequences of a very bad design decision.  Personally, I'd call it an utterly indefensible and incompetent design decision. The only passable excuse for making that decision would be inexperience. And now you unfortunately are the one who gets to experience why it's a horrible design decision.